# Importing postgresql arrays to hive

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I've been using `Sqoop` to move data between `Postgresql` tables and `Hive`. But apparently `Sqoop` does not support the `Postgresql` array type.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql has a function called `array_to_string`. You can utilize that to transform your array to a string.

To illustrate, here is the table in `postgresql`:

```
=# select * from albums;
  id  | album_id  | names 
-----------+-------+-----
 123  | {1,2,3,4} | test
(1 row)
=#
```

As you see the `album_id` has array as type, more specifically an array of integers.

Now, to import this from my database called `mydb` I use the following command:

```sh
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb \
--query "select id, array_to_string(album_id,',','*'), names \
         from albums where \$CONDITIONS" \
--split-by id \
--target-dir albums
```

After that you can create create an external Hive table with the following parameters:

```
collection.delim        $                   
field.delim             ,
```

Comment: Please provide example. I'm using array_to_string(ARRAY[album_id],',') showing null values in hive table.Please help me.